# (Google map javascript api) - won't display user's current location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I used a 3rd API to locate user's current location then feed the latlng to the initMap function but nothing is showing except a grey screen where the map should be. I also checked the console for errors but there are none. Console.log also return the latlng object with the right values in it. Here is the code:

```
<script>
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    var pos;
    $.get( "http://ip-api.com/json", function(data) {
       pos = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lon);
    });
    function initMap() {
       var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
         zoom: 14,
         center: pos,
         mapTypeControl: false
       });
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: pos,
         map: map,
         draggable: false,
         animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
         title: 'Gotcha!'
       });
       marker.setMap(map);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: We don't see when do you call initMap ?

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous.  You need to use the returned data in it's callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function (){
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var pos;
        $.get( "http://ip-api.com/json", function(data) {
          pos = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lon);
          initMap();
        });

        function initMap() {
           var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
             zoom: 10,
             center: pos

           });
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: pos,
             map: map,
             draggable: false,
             animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
             title: 'Gotcha!'
           });
        }
      }

  </script>
```